# Data does not pass through service to other controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm trying to pass my my data from controller 1 to controller 2 but when I log the data in controller 2 it returns a value of undefined. The reason why I used jquery for the request of data is because I'm using datatables and I don't know how to do event binding with angularjs and datatables framework. I would like to know if my implementation of factory service is correct in accordance to controller 1 sending data to it, cause I think that's where my problem is right now. The data is not going through the factory service.

Factory Service

```js
app.factory('profilingFactory', function() {
    var factoryData = {};
    var factoryModel = {};
    
    factoryData.setModel = function(key, value) {
        factoryModel[key] = value;
    }
    
    factoryData.getModel = function(key) {
        return factoryModel[key];
    };
    
    return factoryData;
    
});
```

Controller 1

```js
app.controller('profilingController', function($scope, $http, $window, profilingFactory) {
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        
        $scope.table = $('#table_profile').DataTable ({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/getProfilesData",
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "applicant_id"},
                {"data": "application_type"},
                {"data": "last_name"},
                {"data": "middle_name"},
                {"data": "first_name"},
                {"data": "birth_date"},
                {"data": "address"},
                {"data": "sex"},
                {"data": "date_applied"},
                {
                    "data": "applicant_id",
                    "mRender":  function (data, type, full) {
                        var editLink = '<button id="editFunc" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-id="' + data + '">Edit</button>';
                        //var editLink = '<a id="editFunc" class="editFunction" href="/editProfiles?applicant_id=' + data + '">Edit</a>';
                        var deleteLink = '<button class="btn btn-primary" id="deleteButtonFunc" type="button" data-id="'+ data +'">Delete</button>';
                        return (editLink + " " + "  |  " + " " + deleteLink);
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#editFunc', function(e) {
            
            var clickedEdit = $(this);
            var id = clickedEdit.attr("data-id");
            var url = "/editProfiles?applicant_id=" + id;
            var editData = {
                    editId: id
            }
            //$(location).attr('href', url);
            $http.get('/getEditProfilesData/', {params: editData}).then(function(response) {
                //this is orignally what I inteded. I only put a string to test if the service is working
                profilingFactory.setModel('proFactor', response.data);
            });
            
        });
        
        
        $scope.stringXample = "Yeh";
        //$scope.editProfiles = appData;
        
        $('body').on('click', '#deleteButtonFunc', function(e){
        
            var clicked = $(this);
            var id = clicked.attr("data-id");
            
            var deleteData = {
                    deleteId: id
            }
            
            $http.get('/delProfileData/', {params: deleteData}).then(function(response) {
                clicked.parents("tr").remove();
                alert("User info successfully removed");
            });
            //Optional delete Row after 
        });
        
    });
```

Controller 2

```js
app.controller('editProfliesController', function($scope, $http, $window, profilingFactory) {
    $scope.value = profilingFactory.getModel('proFactor');
    console.log($scope.value);
});
```

HTML

```html
<div class="row">
                    <h1 class="header-edit">Basic Information</h1>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Last Name:</label> <input type="text"
                                class="form-control" name="pwd" value="{{appData.last_name}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">First Name:</label> <input type="text"
                                class="form-control" name="email" value="{{appData.first_name}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Middle Name:</label> <input type="text"
                                class="form-control" name="pwd">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Birth:</label> <input type="date"
                                class="form-control" name="pwd" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: This behaviour may be because you are performing **setModel** inside a Promise. Looks like before your promise could resolve in Controller 1  , Controller 2 is getting loaded. Just to confirm this, can you try moving out the **setModel** outside **http.get** and see if it works?

Comment: I tried moving out setModel in $http and it still returns a value of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code locally. Let me elaborate the issue first as I understand it.

Controller1 and Controller2 are already loaded on initial page render. Once loaded, Controller2's "function" will not execute again.
You actually need to make part of it fire again after you have finished with $http.get in Controller1.
You can make use of **$watch** (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to achieve it.

Keep your **setModel** inside $http.get only and change your Controller2 logic to below and try again:

```
app.controller('editProfliesController', function ($scope, $http, $window, profilingFactory) {
                $scope.$watch(function () { return profilingFactory.getModel('proFactor') }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal!==oldVal)
                    console.log(newVal);
                });
            });
```

**Full code** (minimal reproducible example)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.factory('profilingFactory', function () {
        var factoryData = {};
        var factoryModel = {};

        factoryData.setModel = function (key, value) {
            factoryModel[key] = value;
        }

        factoryData.getModel = function (key) {
            return factoryModel[key];
        };
        return factoryData;
    });

    app.controller('profilingController', function ($scope, $http, $window, profilingFactory) {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').on('click', '#editFunc', function (e) {
                                
                //$(location).attr('href', url);
                $http.get('/getEditProfilesData/', { params: "" }).then(function (response) {
                    // I will not land here since call will fail for me. I am setting model in fail function below
                    // profilingFactory.setModel('proFactor', "hello world");
                }, function (response) {
                        profilingFactory.setModel('proFactor', "hello world");
                });

            });
            $scope.stringXample = "Yeh";
            //$scope.editProfiles = appData;
            $('body').on('click', '#deleteButtonFunc', function (e) {

                var clicked = $(this);
                var id = clicked.attr("data-id");

                var deleteData = {
                    deleteId: id
                }

                $http.get('/delProfileData/', { params: deleteData }).then(function (response) {
                    clicked.parents("tr").remove();
                    alert("User info successfully removed");
                });
                //Optional delete Row after 
            });
        });
            });
            app.controller('editProfliesController', function ($scope, $http, $window, profilingFactory) {
                $scope.$watch(function () { return profilingFactory.getModel('proFactor') }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal!==oldVal)
                        console.log(newVal);
                });
            });
    </script>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <input type="button" id="editFunc" value="Edit"/>
        <div ng-controller="profilingController"></div>
        <div ng-controller="editProfliesController"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this solution yet it does not log anything. It seems like it doesn't read the code within controller 2 (not sure about this one ) since it does not show what the log for newVal is, it doesn't even show if it's undefined or anything. But when I log a string of words outside the $scope.$watch it does log with a value.

Comment: could it be that it that my service factory isn't set up right to take in the data from controller 1?

Comment: It worked fine locally when I tried. You can try to log in controller1 to check if your factory model is setting up correctly. Can you also share the html? Just want to see how controllers are used there. You can update the question.

Comment: Also see if any errors in console. Verify the http get is success

Comment: I updated the post. Btw there were no errors in the console and I checked the network if there was error in the request but turns out its all good. oh and btw you're also using the service in this post in your local setup right (just wanted to clarify maybe you declared it in a different way)?

Comment: The HTML is not helping to understand how you have placed your controllers. Anyways, I have updated my answer with code I am using. It's minimal reproducible example. I just have one "editFunc" button in UI.